# OSGi + JPA(postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, jpa, osgi, eclipselink

I tried to use JPA in OSGi and faced with this exception:

```
 javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named test
```

There are simple entity class, file "persistence.xml" in META-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>org.test.Room</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="12345"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>

    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Activator:

```
package org.test;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    private static BundleContext context;
    static BundleContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        Activator.context = bundleContext;
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        Activator.context = null;
    }
}
```

Manifest.mf:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Test
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.test
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: org.test.Activator
Import-Package: javax.persistence;version="2.0.3", 
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",
 org.postgresql;version="8.3.604"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
```

And error:

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in
>   org.test.Activator.start() of bundle org.test.  at
>
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
>
> > at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1131)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
> >     Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence
> >     provider for EntityManager named test  at
> >     javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown
> >     Source)  at
> >     javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown
> >     Source)  at org.test.Activator.start(Activator.java:23)  at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
> >     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
> >     ... 12 more  Root exception: 
> >     **javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named test**  at
> >     javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown
> >     Source)  at
> >     javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown
> >     Source)  at org.test.Activator.start(Activator.java:23)  at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
> >     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1131)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
> >     at
> >     org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

persistence.xml is works correctly in a simple java project, but in OSGi plug-in I have this problem. What's wrong?

Comment: Can't see imports of persistence provider classes you've mentioned in `persistence.xml` Try `DynamicImport-Package: org.eclipse.*, ....` in your Manifest

Comment: thank you for answer, but I still have this error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the persistence.xml path as a MANIFEST.MF header, like so:

```
Meta-Persistence: META-INF/persistence.xml
```

Though for EclipseLink the following header may be necessary (header value is comma separated list of PU names):

```
JPA-PersistenceUnits: test
```

Comment: Good stuff =)   OSGi is quite well specified, the enterprise spec has a fair bit of info on JPA http://www.osgi.org/Specifications/HomePage that you may find useful