# No Persistence provider error for the OSGI bunfle with JPA support

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle

I have created small OSGI buldle project with the JPA2.0 support to persist the Student(Entity class) Object.

I would be able to start this service successfully.

I have created another client bundle project to access this service. When I try to start the client buldle service I am gettting the bellow error

**Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named StudentJPAService**

**Please find the full stacktrace bellow**

```
!ENTRY StudentJPAClient 4 0 2013-03-04 14:17:21.846
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in student.jpaclient.Activator.start() of bundle StudentJPAClient.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.student.jpaservice.serviceimpl.StudentDAOService.persist(StudentDAOService.java:16)
    at student.jpaclient.Activator.start(Activator.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named StudentJPAService
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at com.student.jpaservice.util.StudentUtil.<clinit>(StudentUtil.java:11)
    ... 17 more
Root exception:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.student.jpaservice.serviceimpl.StudentDAOService.persist(StudentDAOService.java:16)
    at student.jpaclient.Activator.start(Activator.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named StudentJPAService
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at com.student.jpaservice.util.StudentUtil.<clinit>(StudentUtil.java:11)
    ... 17 more
```

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: StudentJPAService
Bundle-SymbolicName: StudentJPAService;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.student.jpaservice.actovator.Activator
Import-Package: javax.persistence;version="1.1.0",
 org.osgi.framework
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Export-Package: com.student.jpaservice.actovator,
 com.student.jpaservice.model,
 com.student.jpaservice.service,
 com.student.jpaservice.serviceimpl,
 com.student.jpaservice.util
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Meta-Persistence: META-INF/persistence.xml
Bundle-ClassPath: ../lib/j2ee.jar,
 ../lib/javax.j2ee.persistence.jar,
 ../lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar,
 .
JPA-PersistenceUnits: StudentJPAService
```

I can see the same problem in bellow post, But It didnt help me to solve my issue.
[OSGi + JPA(postgresql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879827/osgi-jpapostgresql)

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that, in your bundle, you haven't defined any persistence manager such as Hibernate, Eclipse Link, whatever...

Check your dependency tree, in your import package you only have defined two packages, the osgi core and the JPA, but JPA is just an specification (interfaces), you need a engine that implements these interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for youranswer. Do you have any idea which engine we can use for these interfaces?

Comment: Yes, there are several ORM that implements JPA. Some examples are: Hibernate, EclipseLink, TopLink or OpenJPA. I think most popular are Hibernate and EclipseLink.

Hibernate is the most popular, powerful and flexible ORM, but it is also the heaviest and the hardest to learn.
In the other hand EclipseLink is a lightweight ORM, but it's not as powerful as hibernate.

Comment: You can take a look to the next issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569522/hibernate-or-eclipselink

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is tantamount to thread necromancy, but I struggled with this same problem for a while myself until I stumbled upon the solution of bypassing the persistence provider lookup wholesale.

Using this code...

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = new org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider().createEntityManagerFactory("unit_name_here", properties);
    EntityManager manager = emf.createEntityManager();
```

... I call into EclipseLink directly and ignore the whole service provider lookup.  I realize that's not super portable in the sense that you can't swap out persistence providers without recompiling the module, but I also can't remember the last time I wanted to do that.

Hope this helps somebody in the future and saves them the day and a half of hair pulling I went through!

Answer (score 1):

I propose to use Aries JPA together with either OpenJPA or Eclipselink as a persistence provider. I would recommend OpenJPA at the moment as Eclipselink support is still very fresh.

For a complete example you can see my [Apache Karaf DB tutorial](http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2012/01/13/Apache+Karaf+Tutorial+Part+6+-+Database+Access). It contains a jpa example.